# Ingest s3 file to redshift maintaining line order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have files in s3 I need to read into redshift, but I need to maintain the line number from the file somehow.  I tried inserting from a spectrum table into a table with an identity column but it inserts out of order.  Any idea other than rewriting the files with the line number as part of each line?

Comment: In general, the order of rows in a database should be considered to be 'random' unless an ORDER BY (or, in some databases, a GROUP BY) is specified. If you wish to maintain order, you will need that information to be in the source file.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible you can add the line number in the files in S3 then you can just add it like this:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (line_number, other_columns)
SELECT line_number, other_columns
FROM spectrum_s3_table
ORDER BY line_number;
```

Alternatively, you can try to order by your identity_column:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (line_number, other_columns)
SELECT line_number, other_columns
FROM spectrum_s3_table
ORDER BY identity_column;
```